# Cast all columns of numeric type to text when converting a row to json

Tags: json, postgresql, function, casting

I have table with `numeric/decimal` columns and I am converting the rows to json

```sql
select to_jsonb(t.*) from my_table t
```

I need to have the `numeric` columns casted to text before converted to json.

*The reason why I need this is JavaScript don't handle really big numbers well so I may loose a precision. I use `decimal.js` and the string representation is best to construct the `decimal.js` number from.*

I know I can do this

```sql
select to_jsonb(t.*) || jsonb_build_object('numeric_column', numeric_column::text) from my_table t
```

But I want to have it done automatically. Is there a way to somehow cast all `numeric` columns to text before passing to `to_jsonb` function?

It can be user-defined postgres function.

**EDIT**: Just to clarify my question. What I need is some function similar to `to_jsonb` except all columns of the type `numeric/decimal` are stored as `string` in the resulting JSON.

Thanks

Comment: from the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-TYPE-MAPPING-TABLE), the `numeric` json primitive type corresponds to the `numeric` PostGreSQL type, so I don't think there may be some lost information during the json conversion.

Comment: yes that is what I'm saying PG `numeric` is converted to JSON `number` but the `number` can't handle really big numbers correctly when used in JavaScript. E.g. the `(12345678987654321).toString()` prints as `'12345678987654320'` (zero at the end).

Comment: the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e83b4d3dcf638a987387c32277f6f9cd) demonstrates that the jsonb conversion of extreme numeric values doesn't lost any data

Comment: @Edouard did you read what I wrote? The problem is in JS side when the type is `number` so I need to convert it to text before it comes to JS, so it needs to be already as text in JSON.

Comment: can you edit your question and post table create et sample datas as we can try to help you.

Comment: @Philippe I can, but I think it is not needed. What I need is to build json from a row (like `to_jsonb` function), where numeric/decimal columns are converted to text.

Comment: Your real problem is the ma value of integer in javascript that is 2^53-1 or 9 007 199 254 740 991. You can cast your data as text but when you will set your variable in javascript to make an operation, your value will not be the same. Your problem will not be solved by casting your data.

Comment: @Philippe it will, because in JS I will pass the text value of the number to `decimal.js` which will handle the operations with big numbers correctly

Comment: So why don't you set you variable of type decimal.js instead of casting your datas ?

Comment: @Philippe where? I don't understand what you mean. What I receive in JS is a JSON and if the JSON already has number values I cannot do anything with it. Decimal.js is not a data type it is a JS library which can work with big numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This solution converts all the json values into text :

```
SELECT jsonb_object_agg(d.key, d.value)
  FROM my_table AS t
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(t.*)) AS d
 GROUP BY t
```

whereas this solution only converts json numbers into text :

```
 SELECT jsonb_object_agg(d.key, CASE WHEN jsonb_typeof(d.value) = 'number' THEN to_jsonb(d.value :: text) ELSE d.value END)
  FROM my_table AS t
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each(to_jsonb(t.*)) AS d
 GROUP BY t
```

test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0369400fbcef07288a6ec40c608db7db).

Comment: Thanks! This is very close. Only problem is it will convert all numbers to text, I need only `numeric/decimal` columns. Is it possible to do a lateral join without converting to json and in select compare the `pg_typeof` result? Something like this:
`SELECT jsonb_object_agg(d.key, CASE WHEN pg_typeof(d.value) = 'numeric'::regtype THEN to_jsonb(d.value :: text) ELSE d.value END)
  FROM my_table AS t
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL to_key_value(t.*) AS d
 GROUP BY t`

Comment: No I don't see how to make it this way. If you want to not convert integers into text, then you can replace `CASE WHEN jsonb_typeof(d.value) = 'number' THEN ...` by `CASE WHEN jsonb_typeof(d.value) = 'number' AND d.value :: text !~ '^\d+$' THEN ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can run a query like:

```
select row_to_json(row(t.column1,t.column2,t.column_numeric::text)) from my_table t
```

[Result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qu6FZVbcwabZC55Tm6mRBz/0)

Comment: Thanks, but it is almost the same as my example and I don't want this, because I would have to specify the columns explicitely. I don't want to handle the columns I want some function which will handle it automatically,

Comment: Besides, this doesn't use the column names.